# JAVA bean method fails when called from SSJS but not from JAVA

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a JAVA Class that is defied as a managed-bean. The code below is a stripped down version of it:

```
package ca.wfsystems.core;

import lotus.domino.*;

public class Utils {

    public static void recycleObjects(Object... args) {
        for (Object o : args) {
            if (o != null) {
                if (o instanceof Base) {
                    try {
                        ((Base) o).recycle();
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        // who cares?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } //end recycleObjects

    public static void sysOut(Object msg){
        System.out.println(msg.toString());
    } //end sysOut
}// End Class
```

The call to recycleObjects(someObject) works fine when called from JAVA Code, but when I call it from SSJS in a button on an XPage called TestError I get the message "State data not available for /TestError because no control tree was found in the cache."
The SSJS code in the button is:

```
WFSUtils().sysOut("In Button");
var vw:NotesView = WFSAppProperties().get(sessionScope.get("ssApplication")).getAppDB().getView("vwWFSForms");
WFSUtils().sysOut("Testing Bean" + vw.getName());
WFSUtils().recycleObjects(vw);
```

where WFSUtils is the name of the managed bean.

the error in the client says:
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=6, col=12: Java method 'recycleObjects(lotus.domino.local.View)' on java class 'ca.wfsystems.core.Utils' not found
JavaScript code

I have searched for the error "State data not available for" but found a single reference aout it when using the Extension Library but this code does not use it.

Comment: I have answered the second part but I couldn't understand the first part. Where did you see the error message "State data not available for /TestError because no control tree was found in the cache."?

Comment: Domino/workspace/logs/error-log-0.xml on the serrver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) in your method.

It's not possible to use varargs from SSJS. Instead, you might call the same method as:

```
WFSUtils().recycleObjects([vw]);
```

It will work in that way.

Comment: Thanks Serdar that did there is peace again :-)

Comment: One thing, I don't have good experience with static methods in Java beans. Sometimes, Domino server might confuse static things. Just keep in mind. I would use a seperate Util class for static fields and methods.